# Python Smart Open egg library going over internet to get dependent libraries

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, egg

I am using AWS Glue in VPC and my VPC does not allow traffic to outside world so I cannot access internet.

I am using SMART_OPEN library as egg file in python shell Job and that file is trying to go over internet for dependent files like boto and others.

How can we create smart open egg file with all dependent files in it and avoid going it to internet so I can use it in my AWS Glue Job.